# How can I use recursion to count the occurrences of a substring in Java?

Tags: java, recursion

I need to count the occurrences of a substring in a larger string in Java using recursion. I get the idea of recursion, but I'm not sure how it applies to problems like these. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have a lot of similar problems too. Any advice for solving a general problem recursively? My biggest concern is finding the base case.

Thanks!

Comment: In the case of this problem, which you wouldn't solve recursively, but rather using a loop, write it as a loop, and then work out how to transform it to a tail recursion.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have to use recursion. As in, it must have a base case and a recursive step.

Comment: Are you given a substring pattern and then asked to count number of occurances in the string?  Or do you have to find all substring patterns and count?

Comment: Did you even try to make your homework yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no really general way of doing it, I don't think. But here's how I'd do it for this problem:

You wouldn't actually solve this using recursion (in Java, at least). You'd write something like this:

```
int countOccurrences(String str, String search) {
  int count = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while (true) {
    i = str.indexOf(search, i);
    if (i == -1) {
      break;
    } else {
      count += 1;
      i += search.length();
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

So, you can rewrite this as a tail recursion, something like:

```
int countOccurrences(String str, String search) {
  return recurse(str, search, 0, 0);
}

int recurse(String str, String search, int count, int i) {
  i = str.indexOf(search, i);
  if (i == -1) {
    // Like the while loop where i == -1, i.e. no more occurrences found.
    // Break the recursion.
    return count;
  } else {
    // Like the while loop where i != -1: an occurrence was found.
    // Increment count, and keep on searching.
    return recurse(str, search, count + 1, i + search.length());
  }
}
```

Hopefully you can see the commonality between the loop and recursive approaches.

Note that you don't need to write a *tail* recursion: you can write a non-tail recursion by dropping the `count` parameter from the `recurse` method, and making the non-terminal case:

```
return 1 + recurse(str, search, i + search.length());
```

It doesn't make too much of a difference in Java, which doesn't perform tail call optimization, but the tail recursive form may be more efficient in other languages (where it can be converted back into a loop, as above).

Comment: I was only given a specific string, but your adapted method did the trick. Do you have any advice for my other problems?

Comment: Given that all you've said is "I have a lot of similar problems too", I would say to apply a similar methodology: write it as a loop first, and then try to translate it to a recursion based on that.